# I get warning of Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active for no reason sometimes

Tags: php, html, session

I've seen many posts regarding this issue but none of them solved my problem ! Some said this happens because user uses `session_regenerate_id(true);` before `session_start();` ! However this is not the case with my code . I've also seen that some said I should remove extra spaces before `session_start();` and I did that but still I get the warning sometime on loading website . After I refresh Boom , session is destroyed and user logged out .

Note* : I get the warning for line 12 (third if statement).

My code at the start of my every page :

```
<?php 
session_start();
require "DB/users-database.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['starttime']) && (time() - $_SESSION['starttime'] > 1200)){
    session_destroy();
} else {
    $_SESSION['starttime'] = time();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}

if(isset($_SESSION['starttime'])){
    if(time() - $_SESSION['starttime'] > 180) {
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: hmmm sounds interesting .

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to regenerate ID from a destroyed session. Let's see what happen, if we say that the 'starttime' index in `$_SESSION` is defined and that `time() - $_SESSION['starttime'] > 1200` is true :

```php
<?php 
//There, you start your session. It's ok.
session_start();

require "DB/users-database.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['starttime']) && (time() - $_SESSION['starttime'] > 1200)){
    //There, you destroy it because `starttime` is set, and time() - starttime > 1200
    session_destroy();
} else {
    $_SESSION['starttime'] = time();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}

//It's true, since $_SESSION['starttime'] was set before, no reason to not been set there
if(isset($_SESSION['starttime'])){
    //Indeed, if time() - starttime > 1200, it's also > to 180 
    if(time() - $_SESSION['starttime'] > 180) {
        //you try to regenerate ID on a session that you already destroyed.
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }
}
```

I think that you expected $_SESSION to be cleaned with session_destroy. It's not. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php :

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. **It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie**. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.

So one solution is to call `session_start()` right after `session_destroy()`, according to the documentation, for your code to work :

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['starttime']) && (time() - $_SESSION['starttime'] > 1200)){
    //There, you destroy it because `starttime` is set, and time() - starttime > 1200
    session_destroy();
    session_start(); //According to the documentation, from this point $_SESSION have been reseted.
} else {
    $_SESSION['starttime'] = time();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
```

Comment: Your answer was complete and your knowledge is respectable . Thank you for your answer. This was good to know that session_destroy does not unset session global variables ! You thought me something useful today and I respect that . Thanks again

Comment: I remember that I longly struggled with sessions when I started learning PHP. It's just experience that spoke for me. I'm glad that it helped you today.

Comment: Sorry just one more question . Do you suggest that I should use unset() function instead of session_destroy() ? Or I should use both ?

Comment: You don't need to. PHP will unset it for you if you call `session_destroy()` THEN `session_start()`.